# Using Lottie Android with vector image (xml) or svg image?

Tags: android, xml, svg, lottie

I'm using [Lottie Android](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android) for animation and I put images (png) in assets folder of Android. And now I want to scale the image base on devices density by using vector image(xml file) or svg image instead but I haven't found any solution yet. Does anyone have experience with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lottie can't do anything with svgs. We need to create the vector assets that we're using svgs for directly inside of After Effects

Answer (score 1):

If you want a scaling, you convert it from image to vector graphic. actually, After Effects don't support .svg files directly. but Adobe Illustrator supports .svg files. if you convert this. it will be scale

- Import .svg files in Illustrator
- Export .ai file (Illustrator format) in Illustrator
- Import .ai file in After effects
- Drag and drop .ai file to a composition
- Right-click the mouse → Create → Create Shapes from Vector layer. [image]
- it works.